# Html table - how to force TD width when table width is 100%?

Tags: html, css-tables

Is there a way to set the length of all TD cells in case when whole table width is set to 100%? In other words I want all table cells moved to the left (but I can't change table width, because this is for other purposes).

I tried in this way:

```
#mytable td {
    width:50px;
}
```

But this is not working when table width is set to 100%. Here is an example how this looks now: http://jsfiddle.net/Rrkky/

Comment: "Other purposes"? Are you sure you don't want to just put the table inside a div, use that div for your other purposes and let the table focus on being a table? Depending on the problem you are trying to solve you might even be better off replacing the entire table  with divs. One div for each "row", each containing one for each "cell".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make 50px plus 50px equal 100% of the available width except by accident. If you just want to put the table on the right, set e.g. `margin-left: auto` on it. But this would not work if the table width is set to 100%.

Comment: Thanks for idea. That helped me to build my html code in different way. I used 'margin-left: auto' and 'margin-right: auto' inside element, so I don't need width set to 100%.

Answer (score 3):

If possible add an extra td with width 100%.

html

```
<table id="mytable"style="width:100%;background:red"><tr>
    <td>TEXT1</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    <td style="width:100%;background:blue">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
#mytable td {
    width:50px;
    background:green
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rrkky/1/

Comment: Thanks. That is pure solution for my problem.